# checking if a username is unique and email is also unique

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using a mongo DB and in it im trying to create new user objects that have a unique email and username field. usually i find myself only caring if one or the other is unique, but i want to ensure that BOTH fields are unique in the database. Id like to change the error code based on which field isnt unique, that way in my frontend when they are typing in a username, that may be unique but not an email. i dont return an in general error such as "User exists"

In the controller, what i have copied into the editor, is im trying to find a user that already exists based on the credentials object. this works, sort of. it will throw the error, but it will also throw a duplicate key error collection. originally i had this statement, and another statement similar to it i.e. `if(usernameExists)...` however it seems that when i do that, it will only throw the first error in the chain and not the second.

maybe i am making this worse for myself than i actually need too. However i really want to know which parts of the new user are not unique so i can throw an appropriate flag.

```
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    profile: {},
    credentials: {
      email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
      },
      //Will Be hashed
      password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
      },
    }...
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

// export the schema
const User = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);

export default User;
```

I've ommitted parts of the code for breavity. and here is the controller for the route im trying to access.

```
//@desc Register a new user
//@route POST /api/users
//@access Public
const registerUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const {
    profile,
    credentials,
    hiddenChannel,
    origin_server,
    channelImage,
    organization,
  } = req.body;

  const userExists = await User.findOne({ credentials });
  // User Auth
  if (userExists) {
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error("User already exists");
  }

  const user = await User.create({
    profile,
    credentials,
    channelImage: channelImage === undefined ? "" : channelImage,
    organization,
    origin_server,
    hiddenChannel,
  });

  if (user) {
    res.status(201).json({
      _id: user._id,
      name: user.name,
      email: user.email,
      isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
      token: generateToken(user._id),
    });
  } else {
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error("Invalid user data");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> but it will also throw a duplicate key error collection.

This is because you have defined `unique: true` in your schema.

Sample code to throw unique errors:

```
const { username, email } = credentials;

try {
    const usernameExists = await User.findOne({ username });
    const emailExists = await User.findOne({ email });
    
    if(usernameExists && emailExists) {
        res.status(400);
        throw new Error("Username and email already exists");
    } else if(usernameExists) {
        res.status(400);
        throw new Error("Username already exists");
    } else if(emailExists) {
        res.status(400);
        throw new Error("Email already exists");
    }
} catch(error) {
    console.error(error);
}
```

Comment: unfortunately ive already had something similar to this and it didnt work, because for some reason it seems to still return old user information, for example if `username = user` and i change the email and password, to something unique, its still returning the `username=user` object... Could this be because of the way i have my data? `credentials: {}` is this because i am using an object? should i destructure the object and just name the fields?

Comment: `credentials` comes from `req.body` right? So when you send a unique credential obj with the request, it still throws a "... already exists" error?? @AustinHoward

Comment: yes, unfortunately. I pulled the credentials out of the object, so instead in the schema it would list each field. now with your sample code, this works. i dont quite understand why a it wouldnt allow a unique object as the field. but regardless... now i am receiving an error of duplicate key using this method... so many questions... not enough answers haha

Comment: To fix my last issue i simply needed to drop the table and recreate it